# `docker build -t` option accepted but no longer tags the new image

Tags: docker

I almost always build new versions of my Docker image by pasting this into the shell:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile  \
  -t ofiscal/tax.co:new .
```

(Once I see that it works I change the tag -- that is, the part after the colon.)

Today when I tried that, the build succeeded, and yet when I run `docker images` I see "" listed for the new image under REPOSITORY and TAG.

I was thereafter able to run `docker tag` to give it the name that I wanted, so I guess it's not a big deal, but I'd like to know what went wrong.

`docker --version` says I'm at `Docker version 20.10.9, build v20.10.9`. (That may have been updated from an older version on my system recently. I don't know how to find out.)

Comment: Perhaps the docker build output can provide a clue?

Comment: Good call! The problem was that the build hadn't completed. Reasonably, Docker would not tag the new image, because it did not have everything I had asked for. (I had looked at the output before but didn't realize it hadn't finished because it mentioned no error. Now I realize I've got to make sure it says "successfully built" at the end.)